# Custom tabs are not responding to pressed state

Tags: android, android-layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/tab_profile_pressed_mdpi" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/tab_profile_unselected_mdpi" />
</selector>
```

And how I set them:

```
((ImageView)tabHost.getTabWidget().getChildTabViewAt(i).findViewById(R.id.single_tab_img)).setImageResource(unselected_img[i]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use `setBackgroundResource` not `setImageResource`. State drawables work on the background image, not the foreground image.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you need another xml file that lays out what will happen when the tab is pressed.

Example:
tab.xml

```
 <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"
    android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_bg_selected" />
```

tab_bg_selected

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:shape="rectangle">
   <gradient android:startColor="#A8A8A8" android:centerColor="#7F7F7F"
        android:endColor="#696969" android:angle="-90" />
</shape>
```

Comment: I copy and pasted it from one of my applications.  It works quite well actually.

Comment: Dude, I use this trick over 100 times in my codebase. Stop already